# $_POST variable is missing

Tags: php, apache, variables, post

I'm losing one variable when i do a POST submit to a php script (example: http://kidspc.com.mx/kidspc2/prueba_get_post.htm).

I think, there is a parameter in php.ini or httpd.conf that is causing apache block this variable, but i don't know what to search.

I try the solution in this post [PHP some $_POST values missing but are present in php://input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input) but the variable still disappear.

is there an apache o php parameter that could cause this? how i can solve this?

**EDIT: Sorry i add the name attribute to the textbox and it's working. please check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888825/post-variable-with-large-value-disappears**

Comment: Apache doesn't 'block' PHP varaibles. If _POST is empty, then PHP didn't receive anything to put into _POST.

Comment: @Marc: Apache itself doesn't, but a "security" module could very well alter the request, keeping certain keys or values from making it through to the script.  Course, such a module would be pretty annoying on a shared host, and if it were on a private server the admin should know about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give your textarea a name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Your textarea does not have anything in the name='someName' field. You need to name it something for it to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You had forgot to set a name to the textarea. A form input without a name will not get posted via HTTP.

```
<textarea name="some_var_name"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the text area element a name attribute.