# Multidimensional post array PHP 5.4.6

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, multidimensional-array, postdata

Please consider the following simple test suite:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo '<pre>';
echo 'raw: <br/>';
print_r($data);
echo '<br/>$_POST: <br/>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '
<form name="form1" method="post" type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   action="postTest.php"/>
<input type="text" name="my1[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="my1[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="my3" value="3 "/>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This returns on most servers running PHP5+

```
raw: 
my1%5B%5D=1&my1%5B%5D=2&my3=3+
$_POST: 
Array
(
    [my1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [my3] => 3 
)
```

as expected. However on my local system with Ubuntu 12.10, Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.4.6, locale tr_TR.UTF-8, it will return

```
raw: 
my1%5B%5D=1&my1%5B%5D=2&my3=3+
$_POST: 
Array
(
    [my3] => 3 
)
```

where my1 array is vanished. Please note that $_POST['my3'] is still there and I don't experience any other issue with non-array $_POST data and I can still see m1 is there from raw data. 
This is really strange behaviour. What could generally cause this issue?

Comment: Just an guess (may waste your extra minute), why `+` is coming at the end of the `raw:` data. Can you please remove the space from the `value` of `my3` field name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following?

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
parse_str($post , $output);
print_r($output);
```

To see if value getting passed to PHP

Comment: It still returns
Array ( [my3] => 3 )

Comment: hmmm.. could be something to do with URL Encoding

Comment: can you remove type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" from the form and test?

Comment: I did it and still the same. BTW, I also tried it changing the locale to en.US with no success. 
I have coded a simple workaround using the idea in thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input . I added the functionality to look for brackets and make arrays out of them, and it seems to be working, so I could use it as the last escape, yet I would still want to solve this issue according to the book, not relying on such attractions.

Comment: Agree, check the comment on http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php Mark Seecof

Comment: can you try 
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
parse_str(urldecode($post) , $output);
print_r($output);

Comment: I had also tried that, with your hint to dig the encoding, but nothing changed so far.

Comment: I am out of options and as far as I can see, this is a PHP bug and I will issue a bug report. Thank you very much for your help so far. I would like to mark your answer as useful, but stackoverflow won't let me do it until I'll have some reputation around here.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess...

[ and ] are not valid in javascript identifiers neither are they valid in xhtml name attributes.

So two ideas:

One server is serving xhtml and the other html.

You are using different browsers and one is more picky about name attributes than the other.

I think you could turn your fields names into my1_0 and my1_1, or similar.

Comment: I also tried with identical server and client parameters (e.g. with the same version of apache and php versus [chrome,firefox]).
I need to get this running as a part of a Prestashop work, so I wouldn't want to play with the core code a lot. Otherwise, a number of workarounds as in your example, could be surely possible.