# PHP $_POST array empty , $_GET intact however

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, post

I have been searching for hours for a fix to my issue.
I have found several similar issues but few of those fixes apply to me , and none have worked so far.

I am filling a database through a post form , but the array turns up empty:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This results in

> Array ( )

The full code to the index.php file:

```
    <?php

print_r($_POST);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Insert games </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <label for="name"> Game Name </label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what this is supposed to do is send the `name` as `$_POST` value to the same file where I can print it.
It works perfectly fine with `$_GET` , and I am aware I can make this specific application without using `$_POST`. But later on in this project I would like to be able to use `$_POST` for more sensitive information.

There have been several debugging codes other posters have been asked to execute, these are the results I got when doing the same:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Results in

> array(0) { }

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($data);
```

Results in `string(30) "name=TestGame&submit=Submit"`
apparently the post data IS visible through this , but I still have no idea how to use this data and why `$_POST` isn't working properly.

I am using Xampp on Windows 7 , Apache and MySQL are active.

I would be very grateful if someone could give me some advice

-Mick

Comment: Wierd, do you change PHP.ini file?

Comment: Do you have an `htaccess` file with any redirects/rewrites in place?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić I have seen with similar problems that there were issues with the php.ini file before. It was said that max_post_size (or something like it) should be 80M and "Read_Order" (again not 100% sure on the name) should be "EGPCS" Both of which were already in my php.ini

Comment: @Andy I'm not quite sure what you mean by that? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @A-2-A It results in once again nothing , only an empty array where the $_POST should have been.

Comment: @Mickioo It doesn't actually matter, I missed your `file_get_contents('php://input');` test. What does `var_dump($_REQUEST);` show when the form is posted?

Comment: 'array(0) { }'  Unfortunately nothing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"` and press submit button.

Comment: Your saying putting PHP code in the HTML without any tags?                          When I replace my action with "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" , it redirects me to a page with that name , which gives me a 404 error.                                  Currently trying while printing that into the action code...

Comment: Yeah, you're right, you should add a php tags, like so: `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`

Comment: Hmm it still has no result , I do not believe the issue is with the action as is works well when I use $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

> Array ( [name] => test [submit] => Submit )

Check your Xampp settings.
You can try action="/index.php" aswell.

Comment: What should I be looking for in my Xampp settings?                                    When I add a "/" infront of my action it just redirects me to the directory above the php file. I'm fairly sure my action is fine? Because it does work using a $_GET method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good temporary workaround provided by @felixsigl on a different post on this site: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input?lq=1)

It goes as follows:

```
function getRealPOST() {
$pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
$vars = array();
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $nv = explode("=", $pair);
    $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
    $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
    $vars[$name] = $value;
}
return $vars;
}

    $_POST = (getRealPOST());
```

This uses the `php://input` string and converts it into a $_POST array which can then be normally used.

I hope this helps someone with the same problem as I have. 
If someone does find out why $_POST isnt working normally , please do let me know though.