# Codeigniter 4 - post 600 input - not return data

Tags: php, codeigniter

let me tell you that I am trying to submit a form with 600 input using codeigniter 4.
in the controller when taking the input array it only takes 98 inputs, for the others it does not show the value
I have increased the input values ​​on the server but everything remains the same.
I would be grateful if you could guide me. Thanks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAznD.png)

Comment: max_input_vars = 600
restart one time xampp...

Comment: `I have increased the input values ​​on the server` - what does that mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP some $\_POST values missing but are present in php://input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change php.ini file setting. For example, to set the maximum number of input variables to 600.

**max_input_vars** = 600